# Вывод изображения из массива numpy в colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, keras

Есть .tif изображения считанные и записанные в массив numpy:

```
train_images = []
for directory_path in glob.glob('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Image_dataset/sandstone/images_train_128_patches_stone'):
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tif")):
        #Считывание изображения в (RGB-1)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, 1)       
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X))
        #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_images.append(img)

train_images = np.array(train_images)
print(train_images.shape) #(1600, 128, 128, 3)

train_masks = [] 
for directory_path in glob.glob('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Image_dataset/sandstone/masks_train_128_patches_stone'):
    for mask_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tif")):
        #Считывание изображения в оттенках серого
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, 0)       
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)  #Otherwise ground truth changes due to interpolation
        #img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        train_masks.append(mask)

train_masks = np.array(train_masks)
print(train_masks.shape) # (1600, 128, 128)
```

Далее кодирую метки для классов изображений масок:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
# Возвращает размерности массивов (уровней массивов)
number_images, height, width = train_masks.shape
print("Размерности массивов: ", train_masks.shape)
print("Class values in the dataset are ... ", np.unique(train_masks))
# Изменение представления массива (перестройка уровней)
train_masks_reshaped = train_masks.reshape(-1,1)
print("Размерности массивов: ", train_masks_reshaped.shape)
#Нормализует метки таким образом, чтобы они содержали только значения от 0 до n_classes-1
#Tакже можно использовать для преобразования нечисловых меток (если они хешируемы и сопоставимы) в числовые метки
train_masks_reshaped_encoded = labelencoder.fit_transform(train_masks_reshaped)
train_masks_encoded_original_shape = train_masks_reshaped_encoded.reshape(number_images, height, width)
print("Class values in the dataset are ... ", np.unique(train_masks_encoded_original_shape))
```

Добавляю в массив с масками измерение с кодом класса маски:

```
train_masks_input = np.expand_dims(train_masks_encoded_original_shape, axis=3)
print(train_masks_input.shape) # (1600, 128, 128, 1)
```

Разбиваю на наборы:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X1, X_test, y1, y_test = train_test_split(train_images, train_masks_input, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 0)
X_train, X_do_not_use, y_train, y_do_not_use = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 0)

print(X_train.shape) # (720, 128, 128, 3)
print(y_train.shape) # (720, 128, 128, 1)
```

И пытаюсь просмотреть соответствия между изображением и маской:

```
import random
import numpy as np
image_number = random.randint(0, len(X_train))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(X_train[image_number], (128, 128)), cmap='BGR')
#plt.imshow(X_train[image_number])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(y_train[image_number], (128, 128)), cmap='gray')
#plt.imshow(y_train[image_number])
plt.show()
```

Вот эта строка отрабатывает нормально и выводит изображение:

```
plt.imshow(np.reshape(y_train[image_number], (128, 128)), cmap='gray')
```

В этой строке ошибка:

```
plt.imshow(np.reshape(X_train[image_number], (128, 128)), cmap='BGR')
```

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 49152 into shape (128,128)

Подскажите в чем причина? Как это можно исправить?

Мне нужно после присвоения меток классов и разбития убедится, что маска соответствует изображению и вывести это на экран.

Судя по числу в ошибке, 49152=128x128x3

Comment: Ну там 3 цвета видимо. Может в `(128, 128, 3)` надо решейпить? А, ну точно, выше же сами пишете шейп `train_images` - `(1600, 128, 128, 3)`

Comment: @CrazyElf, да вы правы )

Comment: @CrazyElf, а можете подсказать какое значение для параметра cmap должно быть у rgb, на cmap='BGR' и cmap='RGB' он ругается

Comment: Мне кажется вам не нужен никакой `cmap`, уберите его. А если палитра будет неправильная, то раскомментируйте строку `#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`

Comment: @CrazyElf, хорошо, спасибо. Оформите в ответ, поставлю галочку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Судя по ошибке `reshape` нужно делать в `(128, 128, 3)`, это подтверждает размерность `train_images` выше по коду: `(1600, 128, 128, 3)`
- В вашем случае скорее всего `cmap` вообще не нужен, а если палитра будет неправильная, её лучше преобразовать в явном виде, как у вас в коде закомментировано `#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)` (или наоборот надо `BGR2RGB`, я точно не помню, но помню, что у `OpenCV` вроде своя родная палитра `BGR`, из-за этого могут быть несостыковки со стандартной палитрой картинок `RGB`).